# Cannot find bower packages

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower, wiredep

I installed Yeoman on snow leopard OSX 6.8. When I run 'grunt serve' I get the following error (it can't find my bower packages):

```
Dream-2:app1 goldenheart$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-05-21 00:17:32 UTC)
loading tasks   2.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 92%
wiredep:app    187ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 8%
Total 2.5s
```

I tried a number of things suggested on other stackoverflow posts, such as installing bower and grunt locally but I'm still getting the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a .bowerrc file in the root of your project. In that file, you can define where bower need to install its packages. Add this into that file:

```
{
  "directory": "... your location ..."
}
```

Comment: Cool, right now mine says: `{  "directory": "bower_components"}` which means it's looking in the root dir of the application for that folder right? (sorry, dumb clarifying newbie question) - but wouldn't it be better to put it in the dir node_modules, which would make my location `node_modules/bower_components` - yes?